# Kafka producer not working in windows

Tags: jms, messaging, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

The kafka producer program given below is not running in Windows through Eclipse while it runs in Unix platform (i.e works fine when I run it in Unix where the kafka broker is hosted).
Is the kafka producer not supported in windows? I am able to ping the ip address from windows machine however. Please help.

```
package kpkg;

import java.util.Properties;
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;


public class KProducer {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "10.xx.xx.xx:9092");
        props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        props.put("request.required.acks", "1");

        ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
        Producer<String, String> producer = new Producer<String, String>(config);
        KeyedMessage<String, String> km = new KeyedMessage<String, String>("SriKafkaTopic" , "SriFirstMessage");
        producer.send(km);
        producer.close();
    }

}
```

Here is the exception error that I get.

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
       at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:90)
       at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:76)
       at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
       at kpkg.KProducer.main(KProducer.java:30)

Here is the contents of server.log

```
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,342] INFO Verifying properties (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,408] INFO Property broker.id is overridden to 0 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,409] INFO Property log.cleaner.enable is overridden to false (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,409] INFO Property log.dirs is overridden to /tmp/kafka-logs (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,409] INFO Property log.retention.check.interval.ms is overridden to 60000 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,409] INFO Property log.retention.hours is overridden to 168 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,409] INFO Property log.segment.bytes is overridden to 536870912 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,410] INFO Property num.io.threads is overridden to 8 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,410] INFO Property num.network.threads is overridden to 2 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,410] INFO Property num.partitions is overridden to 2 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,410] INFO Property port is overridden to 9092 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,410] INFO Property socket.receive.buffer.bytes is overridden to 1048576 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,410] INFO Property socket.request.max.bytes is overridden to 104857600 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,411] INFO Property socket.send.buffer.bytes is overridden to 1048576 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,411] INFO Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to localhost:2181 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,411] INFO Property zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms is overridden to 1000000 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,432] INFO [Kafka Server 0], starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,434] INFO [Kafka Server 0], Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,788] INFO Found clean shutdown file. Skipping recovery for all logs in data directory '/tmp/kafka-logs' (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,789] INFO Loading log 'SriKafkaTopic-0' (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,820] INFO Completed load of log SriKafkaTopic-0 with log end offset 11 (kafka.log.Log)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,854] INFO Loading log 'test-0' (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,855] INFO Completed load of log test-0 with log end offset 2 (kafka.log.Log)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,855] INFO Loading log 'test1-0' (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,856] INFO Completed load of log test1-0 with log end offset 0 (kafka.log.Log)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,856] INFO Loading log 'test2-0' (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,857] INFO Completed load of log test2-0 with log end offset 1 (kafka.log.Log)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,858] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 60000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,861] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,887] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,897] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 0], Started (kafka.network.SocketServer)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:07,974] INFO Will not load MX4J, mx4j-tools.jar is not in the classpath (kafka.utils.Mx4jLoader$)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,004] INFO 0 successfully elected as leader (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,307] INFO New leader is 0 (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$LeaderChangeListener)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,339] INFO Registered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0 with address master:9092. (kafka.utils.ZkUtils$)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,346] INFO [Kafka Server 0], started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,666] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions [test,0],[SriKafkaTopic,0],[test2,0],[test1,0] (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,739] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions [test,0],[SriKafkaTopic,0],[test2,0],[test1,0] (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
    [2014-06-06 16:32:06,387] INFO Closing socket connection to /10.87.145.30. (kafka.network.Processor)
    [2014-06-06 16:32:06,894] INFO Closing socket connection to /10.87.145.30. (kafka.network.Processor)
    [2014-06-06 16:32:06,993] INFO Closing socket connection to /10.87.145.30. (kafka.network.Processor)
    [2014-06-06 16:32:07,093] INFO Closing socket connection to /10.87.145.30. (kafka.network.Processor)
    [2014-06-06 16:32:07,193] INFO Closing socket connection to /10.87.145.30. (kafka.network.Processor)
```

And here is the contents of

```
    2014-06-06T16:24:07.689+0530: 1.216: [GC 1.216: [ParNew: 26240K->738K(29504K), 0.0131100 secs] 26240K->738K(1045312K), 0.0131890 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
    2014-06-06T16:24:08.475+0530: 2.002: [GC 2.002: [ParNew: 26978K->1175K(29504K), 0.0140800 secs] 26978K->1175K(1045312K), 0.0141450 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
    2014-06-06T16:24:08.494+0530: 2.021: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 0K(1015808K)] 1353K(1045312K), 0.0028850 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
    2014-06-06T16:24:08.506+0530: 2.034: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
    2014-06-06T16:24:08.657+0530: 2.185: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.148/0.151 secs] [Times: user=0.15 sys=0.00, real=0.15 secs]
    2014-06-06T16:24:08.657+0530: 2.185: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
    2014-06-06T16:24:08.668+0530: 2.195: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.011/0.011 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
    2014-06-06T16:24:08.668+0530: 2.195: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
     CMS: abort preclean due to time 2014-06-06T16:24:13.672+0530: 7.200: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.922/5.004 secs] [Times: user=0.91 sys=0.02, real=5.01 secs]
    2014-06-06T16:24:13.672+0530: 7.200: [GC[YG occupancy: 8887 K (29504 K)]2014-06-06T16:24:13.672+0530: 7.200: [GC 7.200: [ParNew: 8887K->1559K(29504K), 0.0098440 secs] 8887K->1559K(1045312K), 0.0099560 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
    7.210: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0109290 secs]7.221: [weak refs processing, 0.0000060 secs]7.221: [class unloading, 0.0014740 secs]7.222: [scrub symbol & string
```

And here is contents of state-change.log

```
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,198] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 started leader election for partition [test,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,216] ERROR Controller 0 epoch 8 initiated state change for partition [test,0] from OfflinePartition to OnlinePartition failed (state.change.logger)
    kafka.common.NoReplicaOnlineException: No replica for partition [test,0] is alive. Live brokers are: [Set()], Assigned replicas are: [List(0)]
            at kafka.controller.OfflinePartitionLeaderSelector.selectLeader(PartitionLeaderSelector.scala:61)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.electLeaderForPartition(PartitionStateMachine.scala:335)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.kafka$controller$PartitionStateMachine$$handleStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:184)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:98)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:743)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:772)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$$anon$1.foreach(HashTable.scala:157)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:190)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:45)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:742)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:95)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.startup(PartitionStateMachine.scala:68)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController.onControllerFailover(KafkaController.scala:311)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:161)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.elect(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:63)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:49)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)
            at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.startup(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:630)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:626)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:626)
            at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController.startup(KafkaController.scala:626)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:96)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:34)
            at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:46)
            at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,217] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 started leader election for partition [test2,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,224] ERROR Controller 0 epoch 8 initiated state change for partition [test2,0] from OfflinePartition to OnlinePartition failed (state.change.logger)
    kafka.common.NoReplicaOnlineException: No replica for partition [test2,0] is alive. Live brokers are: [Set()], Assigned replicas are: [List(0)]
            at kafka.controller.OfflinePartitionLeaderSelector.selectLeader(PartitionLeaderSelector.scala:61)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.electLeaderForPartition(PartitionStateMachine.scala:335)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.kafka$controller$PartitionStateMachine$$handleStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:184)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:98)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:743)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:772)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$$anon$1.foreach(HashTable.scala:157)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:190)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:45)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:742)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:95)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.startup(PartitionStateMachine.scala:68)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController.onControllerFailover(KafkaController.scala:311)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:161)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.elect(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:63)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:49)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)
            at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.startup(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:630)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:626)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:626)
            at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController.startup(KafkaController.scala:626)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:96)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:34)
            at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:46)
            at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,225] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 started leader election for partition [SriKafkaTopic,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,235] ERROR Controller 0 epoch 8 initiated state change for partition [SriKafkaTopic,0] from OfflinePartition to OnlinePartition failed (state.change.logger)
    kafka.common.NoReplicaOnlineException: No replica for partition [SriKafkaTopic,0] is alive. Live brokers are: [Set()], Assigned replicas are: [List(0)]
            at kafka.controller.OfflinePartitionLeaderSelector.selectLeader(PartitionLeaderSelector.scala:61)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.electLeaderForPartition(PartitionStateMachine.scala:335)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.kafka$controller$PartitionStateMachine$$handleStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:184)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:98)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:743)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:772)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$$anon$1.foreach(HashTable.scala:157)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:190)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:45)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:742)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:95)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.startup(PartitionStateMachine.scala:68)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController.onControllerFailover(KafkaController.scala:311)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:161)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.elect(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:63)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:49)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)
            at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.startup(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:630)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:626)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:626)
            at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController.startup(KafkaController.scala:626)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:96)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:34)
            at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:46)
            at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,243] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 started leader election for partition [test1,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,268] ERROR Controller 0 epoch 8 initiated state change for partition [test1,0] from OfflinePartition to OnlinePartition failed (state.change.logger)
    kafka.common.NoReplicaOnlineException: No replica for partition [test1,0] is alive. Live brokers are: [Set()], Assigned replicas are: [List(0)]
            at kafka.controller.OfflinePartitionLeaderSelector.selectLeader(PartitionLeaderSelector.scala:61)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.electLeaderForPartition(PartitionStateMachine.scala:335)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.kafka$controller$PartitionStateMachine$$handleStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:184)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:98)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:743)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:772)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$$anon$1.foreach(HashTable.scala:157)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:190)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:45)
            at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:95)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:742)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:95)
            at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.startup(PartitionStateMachine.scala:68)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController.onControllerFailover(KafkaController.scala:311)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:161)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.elect(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:63)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:49)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)
            at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)
            at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.startup(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:630)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:626)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:626)
            at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)
            at kafka.controller.KafkaController.startup(KafkaController.scala:626)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:96)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:34)
            at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:46)
            at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,433] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 sending UpdateMetadata request (Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:6,ControllerEpoch:7) with correlationId 3 to broker 0 for partition [test,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,462] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 changed state of replica 0 for partition [test,0] from ReplicaDeletionIneligible to OnlineReplica (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,463] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 changed state of replica 0 for partition [test2,0] from ReplicaDeletionIneligible to OnlineReplica (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,463] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 changed state of replica 0 for partition [SriKafkaTopic,0] from ReplicaDeletionIneligible to OnlineReplica (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,464] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 changed state of replica 0 for partition [test1,0] from ReplicaDeletionIneligible to OnlineReplica (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,472] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 sending become-leader LeaderAndIsr request (Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:6,ControllerEpoch:7) with correlationId 4 to broker 0 for partition [test,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,472] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 sending become-leader LeaderAndIsr request (Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:4,ControllerEpoch:7) with correlationId 4 to broker 0 for partition [test2,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,472] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 sending become-leader LeaderAndIsr request (Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:3,ControllerEpoch:7) with correlationId 4 to broker 0 for partition [SriKafkaTopic,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,473] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 sending become-leader LeaderAndIsr request (Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:5,ControllerEpoch:7) with correlationId 4 to broker 0 for partition [test1,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,473] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 sending UpdateMetadata request (Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:6,ControllerEpoch:7) with correlationId 4 to broker 0 for partition [test,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,473] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 sending UpdateMetadata request (Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:4,ControllerEpoch:7) with correlationId 4 to broker 0 for partition [test2,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,474] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 sending UpdateMetadata request (Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:3,ControllerEpoch:7) with correlationId 4 to broker 0 for partition [SriKafkaTopic,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,491] TRACE Broker 0 cached leader info (LeaderAndIsrInfo:(Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:6,ControllerEpoch:7),ReplicationFactor:1),AllReplicas:0) for partition [test,0] in response to UpdateMetadata request sent by controller 0 epoch 8 with correlation id 3 (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,491] TRACE Broker 0 cached leader info (LeaderAndIsrInfo:(Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:4,ControllerEpoch:7),ReplicationFactor:1),AllReplicas:0) for partition [test2,0] in response to UpdateMetadata request sent by controller 0 epoch 8 with correlation id 3 (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,492] TRACE Broker 0 cached leader info (LeaderAndIsrInfo:(Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:3,ControllerEpoch:7),ReplicationFactor:1),AllReplicas:0) for partition [SriKafkaTopic,0] in response to UpdateMetadata request sent by controller 0 epoch 8 with correlation id 3 (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,492] TRACE Broker 0 cached leader info (LeaderAndIsrInfo:(Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:5,ControllerEpoch:7),ReplicationFactor:1),AllReplicas:0) for partition [test1,0] in response to UpdateMetadata request sent by controller 0 epoch 8 with correlation id 3 (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,497] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 sending UpdateMetadata request (Leader:0,ISR:0,LeaderEpoch:5,ControllerEpoch:7) with correlationId 4 to broker 0 for partition [test1,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,498] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 started leader election for partition [test,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,568] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 elected leader 0 for Offline partition [test,0] (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,570] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 changed partition [test,0] from OfflinePartition to OnlinePartition with leader 0 (state.change.logger)
    [2014-06-06 16:24:08,570] TRACE Controller 0 epoch 8 started leader election for partition [test2,0] (state.change.logger)
```

Comment: Can you cat your broker logs here?

Comment: I don't have the broker logs right now, but I saw the request did indeed reach to the broker (Ubuntu) as I saw some logs related to socket close with the ip address of the kafka producer(windows). Will send you the logs in a couple of days once I have access to the setup.

Comment: I have edited the body adding logs towards the end. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are a few checks that you should perform:

1. Make sure there's no firewall running on your Unix machine:

   service iptables stop
2. Make sure that your Linux machine has host name, which is **resolvable** from the Windows machine. We had a similar issue (with consumer though), until we've put the broker host name (exactly what's returned by the *hostname* utility) into client's /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing exactly the same problem and I solved it by setting specifying the following two properties in server.properties of the broker:

```
hostname
advertised.host.name
advertised.port
```

P.S. Follow the following link for more details:

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs